# Related Files Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, files, contentversion

I have a component and apex controller that calls/displays all the related files on a record.

How can I filter the returned files by a field that is set on ContentVersion?

ie. only show files if Document_Type__c = Supporting Document

Apex controller:

```
public class SimplyfyFilesCntrl {  
   @AuraEnabled  
   public static List<ContentDocument> getFiles(string recordId){  
     List<ContentDocument> DocumentList = new List<ContentDocument>();  
     Set<Id> documentIds = new Set<Id>();  //store file ids
     List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl=[select id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=:recordId];  
     for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl){  
       documentIds.add(cdLink.ContentDocumentId);  // Document ids
     }      
     DocumentList = [select Id,Title,FileType,ContentSize from ContentDocument where id IN: documentIds];  
     return DocumentList;  
   }  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the `LatestVersionId` from the `ContentDocument` then get the `ContentVersion` entity and the custom field you want.